# Multivariable implicit differentiation, $U=T\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{T}}dT$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

Given the equation $U=T\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{T}}dT$ where $S$ is a function of V and T and V is being held constant, how do we then find $\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}$?

The way I'm explaining this to myself is that it's essentially the same as in single variable calculus when we have some term multiplied by a differential term (which in this case is the factor $dT$), and we want to differentiate with respect to the variable of the differential term ($T$ here), all that happens is that the differential term disappears.

So the answer would be $\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}=T\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{T}}$

Is this correct? What is happening here? Is the chain rule being used subtly? Are there any complications here due to the partial derivatives as opposed to the single variable version?

I realise this isn't a clearly defined question, I'm just hoping for some helpful and relevant remarks.

Comment: The partial derivative of a differential "$\ldots\mathrm dT$"? Are you certain there's no typo there? That would be very unusual to calculate.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment. So is it true (under the given conditions) that $U=T\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{T}}dT \implies\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}=T\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{T}}$? If so, you seem to be saying that it's true for some other reason than that we've taken the partial derivative of the differential? How would you describe what's happening there?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I'm saying that it seems extremely likely that some sort of typo was made in writing or deriving $U=T\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\,\mathrm dT$ (both 1. on mathematical grounds in that I don't know if I've ever seen someone have the need to write a partial derivative of a differential as you did, and 2. Because it's in blatant contradiction to how those variables are used in places like [the Wikipedia article for Helmholtz free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_free_energy).) I can't sort out the source of the typo on my end (without knowing physics).